# Check for NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

I want to check if an NSNumber exists for a property and exclude any cases where the variable is empty, undefined, nil, NULL etc.

Property is defined as follows:

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;

I have been using the following:

```
if (item.id) {
//has a valid id such as 1,2,3,4
}
else {
//does not have a valid id.. could be 0, nil, NULL etc.
}
```

Am I doing this right?

Note, I know it is possible to check it using ([item.id intValue] != 0).  That is not my question.  My question is whether it is also possible to check as if (item.id) and if so why not?

For strings I usually check string lengths but for numbers, my understanding is, the length property is not available.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? Check wether or not the propery is `nil` and if not, check its intValue, or floatValue or whatever

Comment: This is not a double post.  The other answer asked how to exclude.  I have the code in this post in numerous places and want to check if it works to detect good values...  The difference is subtle--it might confuse some people as it has evidently confused you.

Comment: `if (_item.id != nil && [_item.id intValue] != 0)` is the suggested solution to the other question and it is EXACTLY THE SAME for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should avoid using `id` as a property name. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/143882255765923/) for example.

Second, objective-c has a feature: it allows to send messages to `nil` instances. E.g. `item.id.whatever` will always return `nil` (which you can compare to 0) if `item.id` is `nil`. That means, that you can just check `floatValue` of the property: `if (item.id.floatValue != 0)`.

Comment: Ok, so I take it my code above if (item.id) will not work correctly?

Comment: FYI, my property name is in fact different.  I just used generic item.id for simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

You should check it this way:

```
  if (![item.id isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

And if check value against being zero

```
  if(item.id.floatValue != 0)
```

Comment: what is the usecase for the `isKindOfClass`? If the NSNumber is actually a NSNull your code is supposed to crash.

Comment: If you want to compare an objects class with another, you can use it. For use case, I can say, if you want to check an object inherits a specific class, you can use it.

Comment: Yes, but NSNumber does not inherit NSNull or the other way around. Therefore is not of any use here.

Comment: When it's not initialized, it is a NSNull object. Go ahead and check it.

Comment: No, that is plain wrong. If it is not initialized it is `nil`, it is not a kind of any class.

Comment: st, so you are suggesting if (![item.id isKindOfClass:[NSNULL class]] && (item.floatValue !=0) { ?

Comment: I assumed item object is in a collection, so it's wrapped as NSNull. OP's way should also work. This is just another way to do it.

Comment: @user1904273 yes, you can check it that way.